# how to set values in edittext as per spinner selection?

Tags: android, json, android-edittext, android-spinner

I have following response,

```
{
    "1": {
        "name": "abc",
        "mobile_number": "123456789",
        "address": "streetno3",
        "landmark": "landmarksss",

    },
    "2": {
        "name": "def",
        "mobile_number": "123456789",
        "address": "streetno3",
        "landmark": "landmarksss",

    },
    "3": {
        "name": "ghi",
        "mobile_number": "23423423234",
        "address": "abcdefgh",
        "landmark": "usa",

    },
    "4": {
        "name": "vvb",
        "mobile_number": "55666655",
        "address": "xvgghg",
        "landmark": "fghgh",

    },
    "5": {
        "name": "test",
        "mobile_number": "77699231010",
        "address": "pune",
       "landmark": "fghgh",
    }
}
```

I am getting all the names in `spinner` till here it works fine,now what im trying is by default i have abc selected, if i select test from spinner then how can i display his details in my `edittexts`,in short as per name selection i am trying to get and set details in `edittext`

Java code

```
class LoadAllStates extends AsyncTask<String, String, ArrayList<String>> {
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;
        private String test;
        private String username;
        private String usermobile;
        private String useraddress;
        private String userlandmark;
        private String usercity;
        private String userstate;
        private String userpincode;
        private String useremail;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ShippingAddress.this.getActivity());
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait..");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(
                String... args) {
            ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();
            // Making a request to url and getting response
            statedata = new ArrayList<String>();
            dispdata= new ArrayList<String>();

            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(GET_ADDRESS_DETAIL, ServiceHandler.GET);
            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);
            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {

                    jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                    for (int i = 1; i <= jsonObj.length(); i++) {

                        JSONObject user = jsonObj.getJSONObject(""+i);
                        username= (user.has("name")) ? user.getString("name") : null;

                        usermobile= (user.has("mobile_number")) ? user.getString("mobile_number") : null;
                        useraddress= (user.has("address")) ? user.getString("address") : null;
                        userlandmark= (user.has("landmark")) ? user.getString("landmark") : null;
                        usercity= (user.has("city")) ? user.getString("city") : null;
                        userstate= (user.has("state")) ? user.getString("state") : null;
                        userpincode= (user.has("pin_code")) ? user.getString("pin_code") : null;
                        useremail= (user.has("email")) ? user.getString("email") : null;


                        if(username!=null) statedata.add(username+","+usermobile);
                       /* if(username!=null) dispdata.add(username);

                        if(usermobile!=null) dispdata.add(usermobile);*/


                        Log.i("inner",user.toString());
                        }
                    System.out.println("WifeBday"+statedata.size());
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
            }
            return statedata;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            pDialog.dismiss();
            arrallstates = new String[statedata.size()]; // you can also use "result" array instead
            for (int index = 0; index < statedata.size(); index++) {
                arrallstates[index] = statedata.get(index);// or result.get(index);
            }
            // pass arrConuntry array to ArrayAdapter<String> constroctor :
            adapterallstates = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    ShippingAddress.this.getActivity(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, arrallstates);
            System.out.println("adpttest"+adapterallstates);
            spiner.setAdapter(adapterallstates);

            spiner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    /*String abc=statedata.get(position);
                    System.out.println("abc"+abc);*/
                      edtname.setText(username);
                        edtmobile.setText(usermobile);
                        edtlandmark.setText(userlandmark);
                        edtemail.setText(useremail);
                        edtcity.setText(usercity);
                        edtstate.setText(userstate);
                        edtaddress.setText(useraddress);
                        edtpincode.setText(userpincode);
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });

        }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to make POJO class for this type of data, so that data can be managed easily. But if you have not taken POJO class then now you can take the spinner data from its position and split it to print in EditText.

Suppose if you get data in **data** string on ItemSelected in spinner you can follow the below code and print it in the edittext.

```
String split[]=data.split(",");
String name=split[0];
String mobile=split[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

you have two option

1.Create the custom spinner adapter like below example

**CustomAdapter.java**

```
 /***** Adapter class extends with ArrayAdapter ******/
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList data;
    public Resources res;
    SpinnerModel tempValues=null;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    /*************  CustomAdapter Constructor *****************/
    public CustomAdapter(
                          CustomSpinner activitySpinner, 
                          int textViewResourceId,   
                          ArrayList objects,
                          Resources resLocal
                         ) 
     {
        super(activitySpinner, textViewResourceId, objects);

        /********** Take passed values **********/
        activity = activitySpinner;
        data     = objects;
        res      = resLocal;

        /***********  Layout inflator to call external xml layout () **********************/
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

      }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,ViewGroup parent) {
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    // This funtion called for each row ( Called data.size() times )
    public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        /********** Inflate spinner_rows.xml file for each row ( Defined below ) ************/
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_rows, parent, false);

        /***** Get each Model object from Arraylist ********/
        tempValues = null;
        tempValues = (SpinnerModel) data.get(position);

        TextView label        = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.company);
        TextView sub          = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.sub);
        ImageView companyLogo = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.image);

        if(position==0){

            // Default selected Spinner item 
            label.setText("Please select company");
            sub.setText("");
        }
        else
        {
            // Set values for spinner each row 
            label.setText(tempValues.getCompanyName());
            sub.setText(tempValues.getUrl());
            companyLogo.setImageResource(res.getIdentifier
                                         ("com.androidexample.customspinner:drawable/"
                                          + tempValues.getImage(),null,null));

        }   

        return row;
      }
 }
```

**spinner_rows.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:padding="3dip"
>
    <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/image"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         />
    <TextView
         android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"
         android:padding="3dip"
         android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
         android:textColor="@drawable/red"
         android:textStyle="bold"
         android:id="@+id/company"
         android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
     <TextView
         android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"
         android:padding="2dip"
         android:textColor="@drawable/darkgrey"
         android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
         android:id="@+id/sub"
         android:layout_below="@+id/company"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**SpinnerModel.java**

```
public class SpinnerModel {

        private  String CompanyName="";
        private  String Image=""; 
        private  String Url="";

        /*********** Set Methods ******************/
        public void setCompanyName(String CompanyName)
        {
            this.CompanyName = CompanyName;
        }

        public void setImage(String Image)
        {
            this.Image = Image;
        }

        public void setUrl(String Url)
        {
            this.Url = Url;
        }

        /*********** Get Methods ****************/
        public String getCompanyName()
        {
            return this.CompanyName;
        }

        public String getImage()
        {
            return this.Image;
        }

        public String getUrl()
        {
            return this.Url;
        }   
  }
```

**activity_custom_spinner.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent">

      <TextView
          android:paddingTop="20dip"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

      <Spinner
          android:id="@+id/spinner"
          android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
          android:prompt="@string/defaultText"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"

          />

      <TextView
          android:paddingTop="20dip"
          android:paddingLeft="20dip"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/output"
          />

  </LinearLayout>
```

**CustomSpinner.java**

```
public class CustomSpinner extends Activity {

    /**************  Intialize Variables *************/
    public  ArrayList<SpinnerModel> CustomListViewValuesArr = new ArrayList<SpinnerModel>();
    TextView output = null;
    CustomAdapter adapter;
    CustomSpinner activity = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_custom_spinner);

        activity  = this;

        Spinner  SpinnerExample = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        output                  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.output);

        // Set data in arraylist
        setListData();

        // Resources passed to adapter to get image
        Resources res = getResources(); 

        // Create custom adapter object ( see below CustomAdapter.java )
        adapter = new CustomAdapter(activity, R.layout.spinner_rows, CustomListViewValuesArr,res);

        // Set adapter to spinner
        SpinnerExample.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Listener called when spinner item selected
        SpinnerExample.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View v, int position, long id) {
                // your code here

                // Get selected row data to show on screen
                String Company    = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.company)).getText().toString();
                String CompanyUrl = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.sub)).getText().toString();

                String OutputMsg = "Selected Company : \n\n"+Company+"\n"+CompanyUrl;
                output.setText(OutputMsg);

                Toast.makeText(
                        getApplicationContext(),OutputMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
                // your code here
            }

        });
    }

    /****** Function to set data in ArrayList *************/
    public void setListData()
    {

        // Now i have taken static values by loop.
        // For further inhancement we can take data by webservice / json / xml;

        for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {

            final SpinnerModel sched = new SpinnerModel();

              /******* Firstly take data in model object ******/
               sched.setCompanyName("Company "+i);
               sched.setImage("image"+i);
               sched.setUrl("http:\\www."+i+".com");

            /******** Take Model Object in ArrayList **********/
            CustomListViewValuesArr.add(sched);
        }

    }

  }
```

2. Create a bean type arraylist and store all detail in same order in which you are storing inside arrallstates and in onItemSelected method of spinner you always get the position and in both array list you have same position of data so now fetch data from bean type array list and then set it as you want

Comment: thanks but i already seen that here http://androidexample.com/Custom_Spinner_With_Image_And_Text_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=84&aaid=107